# How can I optimize this macro that sorts and formats SQL data?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an excel program that sorts and formats raw SQL data. I have a macro that takes awhile to run through the data, I would like to optimize it.

This macro runs through approximately 3,500 lines of data and deletes memberships that do not match my parameters.

```
Sub MemDel()
    Dim Row As Long
    For Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(RowToTest, 1)
    If .Value <> "SILV" _
    And .Value <> "AARP" _
    And .Value <> "REA" _
    And .Value <> "SILVFIT" _
    Then _
    Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of deleting one by one, you can build up a range of rows to delete with `Union`. Then delete in one step at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately that took about a minute longer, which surprised me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you'd implement @BigBen's suggestion:

```
Sub MemDel()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For Each CheckCell In ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
        Select Case CheckCell.Value
            Case "SILV", "AARP", "REA", "SILVFIT"   'do nothing
            Case Else:  If rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = CheckCell Else Set rDel = Union(rDel, CheckCell)
        End Select
    Next CheckCell

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```